# With Spring do you still need a java application server and when?

Tags: spring

looks to me you need tomcat or some other servlet engine for the web part.
what about data access part using hibernate and jms? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you don't need an application server, you can see Spring as a proprietary, modular application server implementation / adapter. But you still need an a servlet container.

- Data access part: you can use [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) and some standalone connection pool
- [jms](/questions/tagged/jms): Spring is not a JMS provider, but it nicely integrates POJOs with any JMS provider
- Spring also has comprehensive transactions support
- Finally you have [jmx](/questions/tagged/jmx) and [aop](/questions/tagged/aop) support built-in and easy integration with bean validation, [jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa), web services, [rmi](/questions/tagged/rmi), [jci](/questions/tagged/jci), task scheduling, caching...

As you can see you can either use certified application server and Java EE stack or built on top of Tomcat and pick Spring modules you need. Sometimes Spring uses standard Java EE APIs (like JPA), more often it builts its own.

Comment: for the transaction part, what if container managed transaction is required?

Comment: @Bobo: you can either use [`JtaTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html) or some external transaction managers like Bitronix or Atomikos.